# Restful api using Slim php returns empty if array contains arrays

Tags: php, arrays, rest, api, slim

Before I start, I want to let you know I'm really a noob in `PHP` and this is the first API I'm making.

It works pretty good if I want to echo one array of information (for example food details), but when I try to do the same with multiple items it returns empty.

I've checked the variable values in debug. It's fine in debug and I see an array which contains multiple sub arrays.

My code

```
$app->get('/allfoods', 'authenticate', function () use ($app) {
global $user_id;
$db = new FoodHandler();

// In here i get foods with their details via mysql 
$result = $db->GetAllFoods();
$response = array();
$response["error"] = false;
$response["foods"] = array();

// looping through result and preparing food array
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tmp = array();
    $tmp['food_id'] = $row['food_id'];
    $tmp['food_name'] = $row['food_name'];
    $tmp['food_desc'] = $row['food_desc'];
    $tmp['food_category'] = $row['food_category'];
    $tmp['food_creationDate'] = $row['food_creationDate'];
   array_push($response["foods"], $tmp);
}
echoRespnse(200, $response);});
```

My output function (which works great if there is no array in my array)

```
function echoRespnse($status_code, $response) {
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
    // Http response code
    $app->status($status_code);
    // setting response content type to json
    $app->contentType('application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}

$app->run();?>
```

What is my setup?

- Localhost wamp with php 7.2.4
- Apache 2.4.33
- Mysql 5.7.21

I'm also using Postman to send my request (I also tried it in `C#`, both give back empty content)

Comment: Change your method declaration to `function ($request, $resp)  use ($app)` and then you can use `return $resp->withJson ( $response );` instead of your `echoRespnse()` call.

Comment: My Bad @Furgas i wanted to check if api works and forgot to change it back to $response

Comment: There is a slight chance that `json_encode` returns `false`, that is, there is an error when encoding to JSON. Better check for that.

Comment: @Furgas you are right It returns false.

Comment: But when its an array of string or 'Test' it works fine.

Comment: @SaeedAsgari Use `$error = json_last_error_msg();` function to examine the cause of this error.

Comment: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded This is what i got i checked my mysql result.
Some of the datas are Int and Double. And some of the varchars are in Farsi which is a utf-8 supported language. I will remove items one by one to see which one cause this problem .

Comment: @NigelRen I think you should add this as an answer. It is the proper way of returning JSON in Slim. And it also would catch `json_encode` error and throw an exception with details.

Comment: @SaeedAsgari Add another question regarding `json_encode` problem if you won't manage by yourself.

Comment: Ok the problem is if i have Farsi characters in it.if i remove that field then it works fine. Thanks for your help @NigelRen

Answer (score 0):

I see several issues with your code. First, there is a problem with your route definition. When defining a route, you should pass two arguments to the `get` method: a pattern (a string,`/allfoods` in your case) and an instance of `Clousure` (a callable, your route callback, the anonymous function in your case.) [More details in official docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html).

So, first thing is to remove the `authenticate` string from method parameters and change your route definition to this:

```
$app->get('/allfoods', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    // Body of the function goes here
});
```

Please note I also removed the `use ($app)` as you have access to application instance uising `$this` keyword, so no need for that ([described in official docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html) as well).

Second thing is about generating the response. When using Slim framework it is always a good idea to return the `$response` object instead of `echo`ing response ([read more in official docs](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/response.html)). Thisgives you some advantages, for example the helper method `whitJson` helps you whit generating JSON output.

To refine your whole code in a more Slim-ish way:

```
$app->get('/allfoods', function ($request, $response, $args) {
    global $user_id;
    $db = new FoodHandler();

    // In here i get foods with their details via mysql 
    $result = $db->GetAllFoods();
    $data= array();
    $data["error"] = false;
    $data["foods"] = array();

    // looping through result and preparing food array
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tmp = array();
        $tmp['food_id'] = $row['food_id'];
        $tmp['food_name'] = $row['food_name'];
        $tmp['food_desc'] = $row['food_desc'];
        $tmp['food_category'] = $row['food_category'];
        $tmp['food_creationDate'] = $row['food_creationDate'];
       array_push($data["foods"], $tmp);
    }
// Return JSON data using helper method
return $response->withJson($data);
}
```

And you won't need the `echoResponse` function anymore.

Comment: Salam Nima, 
Thanks for your help. im new to php so bare with me please. When i use your code I get this error in my Postman 
 ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected in C:\wamp\www\v1\index.php on line

My Rest Request has no parameters only api as Authorization
Do you have a telegram so we can talk about this further.

Comment: Salam :) No worries, we're all here to help, but you should describe your problem more precisely. This does not to be related to the part of code you mentioned in your question. In the error you mention, it does not indicate which line of index.php caused the error to raise. Could you please paste that part of index.php?

Comment: <span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function {closure}(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected in C:\wamp\www\v1\index.php on line
                <i>194</i>

Comment: Line 194 which is 
$app->get('/allfoods', function ($request, $response, $args) {

Comment: do you want to check my project via teamviewer , anydesk or skype?

Comment: Are you using any middle-ware? I prefer to solve the problem here on SO, it might come handy for others some day.